# Cypher retrieve nodes matching ALL nodes in a set

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to return nodes that match all nodes in a set connected to my start node. As a minimal example, say I have `Record`s for `GDP` and `Population` for several countries. A user executes a `Query` that `FILTERS_BY Country=Japan` and by `DataType = GDP`. I would like to return all records that are `GROUPED_BY` Japan *and* `GROUPED_BY` GDP.

The minimal graph can be constructed as follows:

```
CREATE
(r1:Record {name: "China GDP"}),
(r2:Record {name: "China Population"}),
(r3:Record {name: "Japan GDP"}),
(r4:Record {name: "Japan Population"}),
(c1:Country {name: "China"}),
(c2:Country {name: "Japan"}),
(s1:DataType {name: "GDP"}),
(s2:DataType {name: "Population"}),
(r1) - [:GROUPED_BY] -> (c1),
(r1) - [:GROUPED_BY] -> (s1),
(r2) - [:GROUPED_BY] -> (c1),
(r2) - [:GROUPED_BY] -> (s2),
(r3) - [:GROUPED_BY] -> (c2),
(r3) - [:GROUPED_BY] -> (s1),
(r4) - [:GROUPED_BY] -> (c2),
(r4) - [:GROUPED_BY] -> (s2),
(q:Query {summary: "Looking for Japan GDP"}),
(q) - [:FILTERED_BY] -> (c2),
(q) - [:FILTERED_BY] -> (s1)
;
```

This yields the graph shown below:
[image: Graph Overview]

I need to write a query that returns all records that are `GROUPED_BY` both `Japan` AND `GDP` (in this case it is just the one record).

The following query returns all records that are `GROUPED_BY` either Japan *OR* GDP, but I need records that are GROUPED_BY *both*.

```
MATCH (q:Query {summary: "Looking for Japan GDP"}),
(q) - [:FILTERED_BY] -> (filters),
(r:Record) - [:GROUPED_BY] -> (filters)
return r;
```

Yields:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a Neo4j knowledge base article on [performing match intersection](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/) that provides a few approaches to getting the result you want.

(Also keep in mind that node variables should probably be kept singular, as they will only match to a single node per row. Try to reserve plural variables to lists, to avoid confusion in your queries.)

One possible approach would look like this:

```
MATCH (q:Query {summary: "Looking for Japan GDP"})-[:FILTERED_BY]->(filter)
WITH filter, size((q)-[:FILTERED_BY]->()) as totalFilterCount
MATCH (r:Record)-[:GROUPED_BY]->(filter)
WITH r, count(filter) as matchedFilterCount, totalFilterCount
WHERE matchedFilterCount = totalFilterCount
RETURN r
```

Comment: Why are you using size/count? Wouldn't `WITH COLLECT(filter) as filters MATCH (r:Record) WHERE ALL(filter IN filters WHERE (filter)-->(r))` be more efficient? (At least, less convoluted to the Cypher Planner. I can't help thinking that relaying on counts will have subtle bugs)

Comment: Shouldn't be any issues with getting the count of that pattern, that will get the relationship degree from the node itself, so less expensive. As far as efficiency testing, you may want to test the multiple approaches on a larger version of the graph with more nodes and connections.

Comment: @Tezra Your solution does not produce the intended result. Am I implementing it correctly? `MATCH (q:Query {summary: "Looking for Japan GDP"})-[:FILTERED_BY]->(filter)
WITH COLLECT(filter) as filters 
MATCH (r:Record) WHERE ALL(filter IN filters WHERE (filter)-->(r))
RETURN r`

Comment: The direction of the relationship between filter and r is reversed, and it may need the rel type if there are multiple types between the two nodes.

Comment: @Sam Sorry, `WHERE ALL(filter IN filters WHERE (filter)<-[:GROUPED_BY]-(r))` is more correct. You can omit the rel type if that is the only valid linking type between those nodes, but without it, you could also open yourself up to invalid matches if the scheme changes.